# To create a complex Table

Tags: tables

I need to create a table like this:

[image]

The code I wrote is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{a4paper,total={175mm,280mm},left=15mm,top=10mm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
 \multirow{2}{*}{Name of the faculty}  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mr KASHYAP}}  &\multirow{2}{*}{Department}  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{ECE}} \\  
                &\multicolumn{3}{c}{}       &       &\multicolumn{3}{c}{}   \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-8}
 Employee Code  &----  &Scheme  &KTU  &Semester  &Third  &Batch  &A \\  \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Name of the Subject}  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Logic Circuit Design}}  &\multirow{2}{*}{Subject Code}  &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{EC 207}} \\ \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-8} 
 Department  & \multicolumn{7}{l}{ECE} \\ \hline




\end{tabular}
```

But it doesn't give me the desired result. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Name of the faculty &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Mr KASHYAP} & Department &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ECE} \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-8}
Employee Code &---- &Scheme &KTU &Semester &Third &Batch &A \\ 
\hline 
Name of the Subject &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Logic Circuit Design} &Subject Code &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{EC 207} \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5} \cline{6-8} 
Department & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{ECE} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


other codes remain the same. On compilation you get
```

[image: complx]

Answer (score 2):

With ConTeXt natural tables.

```
\starttext
\startTABLE
  \NC Name of the faculty \NC[nx=3] Mr KASHYAP \NC Department \NC[nx=3] ECE \NC\NR
  \NC Employee Code \NC --- \NC Scheme \NC KTU \NC Semester \NC Third \NC Batch \NC A \NC\NR
  \NC Name of the Subject \NC[nx=3] Logic Circuit Design \NC Subject Code \NC[nx=3] EC 207 \NC\NR
  \NC Department \NC[nx=7] ECE \NC\NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]